# Если стоит команда sleep 24 часа, то как можно все ровно общаться с ботом?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, таймер, sleep

> *Язык:* Python

> *Библиотека*: Vk.api

> *Проблема:* Из-за команды sleep(24 часа) он перестаёт отвечать, но как сделать чтоб таймер был и он мог отвечать?
> (Для команды бонус)

> *Код:*

```
if msg == 'бонус':
    if bonus == 0:
        user.coin = user.coin + 1000
        sender(id, f'✅ {user.name}, вы успешно получили бонус.\n Баланс: {user.coin}$', nazad_key)
        time.sleep(86400)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        h = now.hour
        m = now.minute
        s = now.second
        bonus == 1

    else:
        sender(id, f'❌ {user.name}, вы уже получили бонус', nazad_key)
```

*86,400 сек = 24 часа

Comment: 86,400 сек = 24 часа

Comment: А зачем там вам этот sleep?

Comment: Незнаю, мне нужен таймер на 24 часа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение этой проблемы:

```
if event.text == "бонус":
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = now.day
    if now == user.bonus:
        msg(0, "❌ Вы уже брали бонус сегодня, приходите завтра! X")
    else:
        rand = random.randrange(10, 10000, 10)
        user.coin = user.coin + rand
        bonus = now
        sender(id, f'✅ Вы получили бонус в размере {rand} монет!', nazad_key)
```